# どのコミュニティで質問したらよいかわからないときについて

Tags: サポート

スタックオーバーフロー関係のどのコミュニティで質問したらよいかわからないときにはどうすればよろしいのでしょうか？
また、どのような質問をどこですればよいかまとめて書かれているページはないのでしょうか？

Comment: 英語の質問ですか？日本語ですか？日本語なら、メインサイトとメタサイトしかないですが、メタとメインの関係は不明ですか？

Comment: 例えば、数学の問題をプログラミングで解く場合、Mathematics, スタックオーバーフロー  のいずれで質問すべきでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ある話題をどこでするべきかさっぱり見当つかないのであれば、そのキーワードを検索してみてはいかがでしょうか。もし Stack Exchange コミュニティに限定したいのであれば、 http://stackexchange.com/ でコミュニティを横断した検索が行えます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

候補が見つかったうえでどちらが適当か迷っているなら、そのサイトのオントピックを確認してみてください。ヘルプセンターで What topics can I ask about here? を探すか、 `/help/on-topic` でアクセスできます。迷うほどに近い領域のサイトなら、その使い分けについても書かれていることがあります。

例えば Mathematics の場合・・・

> What might be better asked elsewhere
>
> - Research-level mathematics: MathOverflow
> - Statistical analysis: Cross Validated
> - Research level algorithm design, complexity theory, etc.: Theoretical Computer Science
> - Numerical analysis and scientific computing: Computational Science
> - **Algorithm implementation/design, computer simulation and modelling, etc.: Stack Overflow**
> - Other computer science topics: Computer Science
> - Signal processing: Signal Processing
> - Mathematical education, especially about teaching and pedagogy: Mathematics Educators
> - History and development of mathematics: History of Science and Mathematics
>
> <sub>--- https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic より引用。強調は私によるものです。</sub>

とあるので、解法自体がわからない場合には Mathematics （もしくは他のコミュニティ）、それをプログラムにどう落とし込むかといった話は Stack Overflow、といった使い分けになるでしょう。